# Cinematics; Equation of movement

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, particle-physics

What's the difference using the fórmulas v=d/t , or  a=v/t, instead of equations of motion? I dont get it.

Comment: If you already know the path to be taken, along with the time stamp for each position; or having measured the actual path, and the corresponding times, then in either case you have all of the information for the kinematics.

Comment: What equations of motion?  Can you give an example.  Your question is too vague to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those definitions are either for the mean velocity and the mean acceleration respectively, or for the instantaneous speed for non-accelerated motion (the first).   To find the instantaneous velocity, acceleration or actual position over time in the general case  you  need to solve the equations of motion, which will result in different "formulas" than those that you wrote.

Comment: So the first 2 are for the mean, and equations of motion are for instantaneous variables?

Comment: yes, although the first equation is also a solution of the equations of motion for the instantaneous speed when there is no initial speed and no acceleration

Comment: So tell me: imagine I got a pulley that is in rest, and I pull it constantly giving an angular acceleration of x rad/s^2, and I want to discover the time needed to make 5 spins. What fórmula would I use?   Angular acceleration= angular velocity/ time  or I use  final angle=initial angle + angular velocity * time + 0,5 *angular acceleration* time^2.        And why? I think it's the second. But I cant understand exactly why...

Comment: I am not sure what do you want explained about that example, do you want the equations of motion and how to solve it? if so you probably should expand on the setup and put it as a separate question

Comment: Sorry, I clicked on "send" by mistake :)

Comment: Read again please

Comment: To understand why you first need to understand calculus to write and solve the equations of motion or else, accept different formulas for different situations , which were obtained previously in those same situations using the equations of motion. BUt you need to understand in which situation each formula is valid.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the path to be taken, along with the time stamp for each position; or having measured the actual path, and the corresponding times, then in either case you have all of the information for the kinematics.

The more usual problem is that you start with less information, but you know the dynamics: then Newton's Laws of Motion can be used to determine the equations of motion.  The power is in the prediction.

Comment: So tell me: imagine I got a pulley that is in rest, and I pull it constantly giving an angular acceleration of x rad/s^2, and I want to discover the time needed to make 5 spins. What fórmula would I use?   Angular acceleration= angular velocity/ time  or I use  final angle=initial angle + angular velocity * time + 0,5 *angular acceleration* time^2.        And why? I think it's the second. But I cant understand exactly why...